# memgraph service not started after installation on WSL

Tags: installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux, memgraphdb

After installation of debian package of memgraph on windows subsystem for Linux. memgraph is not started automatically.

Install debian package for memgraph. Some errors will be shown for chattr like

> chattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags on /usr/share/memgraph/examples/Europe/snapshots.

After that memgraph is not started. Running `systemctl start memgraph`
gives the

> error Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory.

which is expected as systemd is not supported by WSL.

So, how can memgraph be started in a WSL shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, there is no `systemd` on WSL, which means that Memgraph doesn't run automatically.

Try to run Memgraph manually by executing the following shell command:

```
/usr/lib/memgraph/memgraph
```

The concrete path depends on which Linux do you use.

```
locate memgraph
```

Might help you to figure out the right path.